# 2 borders, layered and different color, width and height

Tags: html, css, border

Not sure how to describe it, so here's a pic:

[image]

This is what I've tried so far, but the span is not visible.

```
.border{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
  width:400px;
  position:relative;
}
.border span{
    border-bottom:4px solid red;
    display:inline-block;
    width:50px;
    position:absolute;
    left:48%;
    bottom:-4px;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain further what do you want with this? is it supposed to be a static element, some sort of progress bar or just a fancy border? Also, are you going to put some content inside this 'span'? What's your HTML like?

Comment: The css you have does exactly what is depicted, so what is the question? Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5K9eu/

Comment: @Brian if you look at that jsfiddle and the image it's not the same. the lines on the side should be aligned middle of the red line.

Comment: @Luciano the title says a border with 2 different colors and aligned.  and I attached an image to go along.  I guess the saying "picture is worth a thousand words" is not valid?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, try this:

HTML:

```
<div class="border"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.border{
  width:400px;
  height: 1px; /* instead of border */
  background: #666;
  position:relative;
}

/* pseudo-element instead of span for cleaner HTML */
.border:before { 
    content: '';
    border-bottom:4px solid red;
    display:inline-block;
    width:50px;
    position:absolute;
    left:48%;
    top:-2px; /* instead of bottom, go top by half the height */
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had answered it with almost the same using pseudo-element.  Deleted my answer so I can choose yours and give you credit :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace bottom by  margin :

```
.border span{
    border-bottom:4px solid red;
    display:inline-block;
    width:50px;
    position:absolute;
    left:48%;
    margin-bottom:-2px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this
css
    div.container{border-top:solid 1px red;padding:0px;}
            div.inside{height:100%;width:100%;border-top:2px solid red;margin:0px;}

html

content

i havent tested but it should work